# ESXi (Free Versions) Notifications when there is sustained high CPU usage

Tags: vmware-esxi, performance-monitoring

I'm looking for a way to have the free version of ESXi notify me (Email is fine) when CPU usage is over 60% for at least 60 minutes. Generally, my CPU usage is around 25%. If it stays high for a sustained period, something is wrong. I don't want to have to check it constantly. How can I setup notifications for certain events?

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to do this natively with the free version of ESXi, but you can use a third party program to do this for you.

I use Veeam One Community Edition. It's free and it's a great product.

https://www.veeam.com/virtual-server-management-one-free.html

Comment: Sounds good, but a 1.5GB download seems rather ridiculous. Hoping there is a simpler solution.

Comment: I don't see how the size of the download makes it any more or less simple, but whatever. At any rate, it's a great product.

Comment: Another alternative I like is using Zabbix. It is a tool specially designed to monitor different kinds of workload. 
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/vm_monitoring
There are a variety of alternative to choose from. Might be helpful:
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/you-cant-have-too-much-monitoring